# Grab random element from CSV file

Tags: java

I'm having trouble grabbing a random element from a CSV file. Here's my code

```
public  String[] generateNames(String Name) 

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(newFileReader("c:\\users\\listofcities.csv"));


Random generator = new Random();

int row = generator.nextInt(1);

String[] arrayValues = new String[row];

        for (int i=1; i<arrayValues.length; i++) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, "\n");
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    //get next token and store it in the array
                    arrayValues[row] = st.nextToken();

                }

            }
            row++;
        }
        //close the file
        br.close();

        return arrayValues;
    }
```

Whenever I have the row value as anything other than 1 I get an arrayoutofbounds exception. Can anyone put me on the right track, cause my code is fucked.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `public int nextInt(int bound)` from `Random` class, which returns value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified `bound` value (exclusive).

`String[] arrayValues = new String[row];` this line produce array with size 0 or 1. So when you try to access `arrayValues[i]` where `i` is greater than size of array it throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with you code is that you are generating values as 0 or 1, so change the random number generation statement to this.

```
 int randomNum = minimum + rand.nextInt((maximum - minimum) + 1);
```

minimum = initial value in range,
maximum = final value in range